# Prevent the application from crashing if one of the threads crashed

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there any way to prevent main thread from crashing?
I want the main thread to keep running after this memory access violation exception happens.

```
std::thread {
    []() {
        for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Hello World from detached thread!\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
        std::cout << "Boom!\n";
        *(int*)(0) = 42;
    }
}.detach();

while (true) {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
```

Comment: Technically it is possible, however you should instead focus on eliminating possibility of access violations and other memory corruption problems.

Comment: So after one thread (which shares the address space with all other threads) has corrupted memory, you want all the other threads to just carry on as if all is well and good and keep using that corrupted memory? Sounds like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: If a thread crashes it can leave the the runtime support library in an invalid state, it could have crashed due to memory corruption caused by itself or another thread.  My usual advice for non-mission critical systems is to - log (if possible) and exit the program as soon as you can.

Comment: If the thread crashed, Crom only knows what it took with it. You're almost certainly better off failing well by allowing the program to die and restart.

Comment: The usual approach when dealing with these things is to use multiple processes. Whatever killed a child process (not just access violations!) will only affect the child, not the parent which can react accordingly.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I guess doing the work in a separate process, not in a thread is a solution, thanks

Comment: What platform are you on?  Windows has mechanisms that *nix lacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sigaction` to install a handler for SIGSEGV that kept that thread busy while main kept running.

```
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t* si, void* unused)
{
    sleep(100000); // or something similar that's async-signal-safe
                   // on your operating system
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        perror("sigaction");
    ...
```

This is of course incredible fragile.  For example, if the thread that generated the SIGSEGV was holding a lock, then it won't be released so other threads can acquire it.

As Ulrich points out, the usual approach to be tolerant to such things is to spawn child processes.  Google Chrome famously started doing this for its browser tabs years back, helping it have a higher level of resiliency than other browsers at the time (who then had to catch up themselves).  Modern Operating Systems make it very efficient to have multiple processes, whereas in older ones threads may have used massively less resources....

Comment: Hopefully nothing is waiting for that thread to finish...  Still, it'll "work".  :-)

Comment: Sure. You *could* do that. But what's the state of the program now? How do you know that anything you do from now on is producing correct results? Also; that won't catch all crashes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: not sure why you're asking me.  It depends what caused the SIGSEGV, Yura might or might not have a feel for what's possible there in the code base in question....

Comment: @Tony I'm not asking you. I'm asking OP by proxy.

Answer (score 5):

Not in general.

One major causes of access violations is memory corruption - a pointer to a data element gets overwritten, or the size of some object gets wiped.  There's only one memory address space in a process.  One of the most likely places for that to happen is in the heap of memory doled out by `new`, `malloc()`, *et al*. And there's only one heap per process.

So any thread that corrupts memory corrupts it for all threads.

Note that in your contrived example, you know you're deferencing a null pointer.  The problem in real code is that you'll never know **why** you're dereferencing a null pointer.  And if the memory you access illicitly isn't at address zero, or some value very close to it, some "kill that thread so the rest can survive" logic can never really know what happened.

You can try to keep running, just like you can try running across a minefield.

And if you do keep running, how do you know your results are valid?  You will almost certainly **never** have tested with whatever exact memory corruption your process is trying to run with.  Because if you had, you would have known about that bug and fixed it, right?

And what are you going to do if your thread dies while it's holding a lock of some kind?